# fetching api is extremely slow (maybe 20 second to respond) . wonder maybe there is a problem in my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

fetching api is extremely slow (maybe 20 second to respond) but the api backend is not slow when i open it from chrome and i see json file . wonder maybe there is a problem in my code

this is how i want fetch an api . should I add more options in it to works normally ?

what i missing in my code.

```
const fetchPosts = async () => {
    setisLoading(true)


    try {
      localStorage.clear();

      const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts?limit=6`
      ,
       {
        method: "GET",
         headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-store', "Content-Type": "application/json" } 
        
        }
       );

 localStorage.clear();
      const data = await res.json();
      setposts(data);
      // console.log(data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    setisLoading(false);

  }
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.clear();

    fetchPosts();
  }, []);
```

I added     localStorage.clear(); to my code because it not fetching if i do not add ..

EDITED :

this is the backend code related to getposts

```
const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;
  const limitValue = req.query.limit || 500;
  const skipValue = req.query.skip  ||  0;
 
 

  const posts = await Post.find(userId ? { bookmarks: userId } : {})
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .populate("author")
    .populate("tags")
    .skip(skipValue) 
     .limit(limitValue)


  if (!posts) res.status(204).json("No posts found");
  else {
    res.status(200).json(posts.map((post) => post.toObject({ getters: true })));
  }
};
```

I just fetch first 8 posts . just 8 , for 8 posts from database it took 25 second . but in google chrome it opens instantly but in my react app took 25 second to fetch

Comment: show back-end code

Comment: Clearing local storage has no effect on fetching data--if it **does** have an effect it's because of something else not shown.

Comment: @paliz I added the backend code related to the problem please look myfriend

Comment: @DaveNewton I do not know . u mean i remove the local storage clear ?

Comment: @DaveNewton  can u give me an optopn that i add to my fetch request . for performance . or can u make an example of my code with axios . i have no clue

Comment: @DaveNewton I found an error . can u look it for me , is this error related to my performance issue ?    the error is :      Error storing data DOMException: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'persist:root' exceeded the quota.

Comment: @paliz I found the problem is my backend code this line ,     const limitValue = req.query.limit || 500;
 but when i change 500 to 8 . performance become great but search function just search between 8 posts . can u tell me how can i fix this issue

Comment: I think the problem is in the backend, that API may take some time to send back the response, or your internet may be down.

Comment: @BennisonJ thanks but i am 1 month stuck in this issue ....

Answer (score 0):

you must use pagination  each request result contain 10 rows more then that it take times

```
 const limitValue = req.query.limit || 10;
 const skipValue = ((req.query.skip || 0)-1) * limitValue;
```

url must like that for example
page one
https://api/x?limit=10&skip=1
for page 2
https://api/x?limit=10&skip=2 and so one

Comment: U mean i remove the infinity loading . and add pagination to my react app after i add this backend code ?

Comment: no and yes the code  i mention at top it;s show how make back-end get 10 row at per request  and front-end it's up to you or  when you are at end of page you need set up event to get next  row ... okay

Comment: it just u understand my problem . atleast can u tell me how can i make fetch request act first ?

Comment: set event when scroll window  to bottom   then fetch request

Comment: can u see this is this file related to my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76156512/search-query-in-react-not-working-properly