# Access to fetch at '' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

Access to fetch at '' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy

Problem is I have 2 domain in my website, but my code just allow me add one CLIENT_URL

cors policy just work for one domain ...

this is my code

in the server.js

```
app.use(cors(corsoption))
```

this is my corsoption.js file

```
const allowedOrigins = require('./allowedOrigins');

module.exports = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  },
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};
```

this is my allowedorigins.js file

```
module.exports = [process.env.CLIENT_URL];
```

How can i add 2 CLIENT_URL into my code . because i tried every solution about headers in front end part ..

thanks .

Comment: Can you share an example of the _exact_ format of `process.env.CLIENT_URL`. I'm suspicious because technically it should not be a URL, it's an origin which is a URL without the path/query/fragment parts.

Comment: @Evert  . thanks for answering me .  do u mean in .env file ?   CLIENT_URL= 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'

Comment: That's incorrect, the origin needs to have the scheme part of the URL. So for example `http://127.0.0.1:3000`

Comment: @Evert I have 2 domain . in one of them working babacode.top   and one of them babacode.ir  not working.  my problem is if i change . env file i just can use one CLIENT_URL .

Comment: I see, can you add a second environment variable and call it something else?

Comment: @Evert I did that . but then babacode.ir working and babacode.top not working ,  i change the code of allowedorigin.js in my code to something like this``` module.exports = ["babacode.ir", "babacode.top"]```   but not worked ,  when i try to add CLIENT_URL  it just rewrite the CLIENT_URL . it just allowed me once .

Comment: you need the `http://` part

Comment: @Evert  this did not worked  . maybe i remove the brackets ?   ``` module.exports = "http://babacode.ir", "http://babacode.top"``` wait a second i deploy and see

Comment: That's not gonna work.

Comment: @Evert yes u right both of them not working now  , the hosting provider said change the module.exports to this , but it did not worked , is it impossible 2 domain fetch from 1 api ?

Comment: No it's entirely possible. You might have another problem, but the missing `http://` is definitely _one of them_.

Comment: @Evert   in hostin panel i change the .env file . see https://i.postimg.cc/MK4Xzfn3/333.png   . but it just rewrite and use one of them , i have to change in my code , so i tried add headers no cors and so one to react , but it seems it is all about backend code , and in my question . there is only 3 file related to cors . even when i change server.js file code like this app.use(cors()) . nothing ... what is wrong

Comment: I'm sorry but it's a bit hard to understand your latest question. I would suggest you start doing some more debugging with `console.log` to see where this goes wrong.

Comment: @Evert thank you man it worked now . i add https:// instead of http  . if u add free time can u look this impossible my another question. now is 5 months , i have that issue   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76142115/fetching-api-is-extremely-slow-maybe-20-second-to-respond-wonder-maybe-there